# SevenZipSharp show current extracting file while doing extraction

Tags: vb.net, sevenzipsharp

I'm using vb.net and was wondering how to show what file is being extracted when extracting an archive. I've already have a workaround but it's "cheaty" and doesn't really display the current file that is extracting.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private listItemIndex As Integer = 0

    Public Sub ext_Extracting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As SevenZip.ProgressEventArgs)
        Dim ext As SevenZipExtractor = New SevenZipExtractor("C:\Test.7z")
        If listItemIndex < ext.ArchiveFileNames.Count Then
            Label1.Text = ext.ArchiveFileNames.Item(listItemIndex).ToString()
            listItemIndex += 1
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer was written by the OP but incorrectly [edited into the question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/13784833/2):

> Ok I got it. I had to add "FileInfo.FileName" into "SevenZip.FileInfoEventArgs" then make a reference to it when extracting.
>
> ```
> Public Sub FileExtractionStarted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As SevenZip.FileInfoEventArgs)
>     Label1.Text = e.FileInfo.FileName
> End Sub
>
> Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
>     SevenZipExtractor.SetLibraryPath("C:\7z.dll")
>     Dim ext As SevenZipExtractor = New SevenZipExtractor("C:\test.7z")
>     ext.BeginExtractArchive("C:\Test")
>     AddHandler ext.ExtractionFinished, AddressOf ext_ExtractionFinished
>     AddHandler ext.Extracting, AddressOf ext_Extracting
>     AddHandler ext.FileExtractionStarted, AddressOf FileExtractionStarted '<---
> End Sub
> ```

Comment: user1888932: If you are interested in gaining rep points from this answer, please post it as your own answer then leave a comment here and I will delete this community wiki.